# I need to Copy a column with Double quotation " sign to another column without Quotation Sign in Excel Using Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please solve it as soon as you can. will be highly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(34), "")
```

Change `A1` with the actual cell where your ID data is, then replicate the formula down.

`CHAR(34)` is the double quote sign.